# Emacs Split frame, split line broken

Tags: emacs

`Make` on `eshell` , the chinese prompt will make the split line broken.

Like this, How to fix this problem ? thanks. Emacs version 24.4

[image]

Comment: what is your terminal and what is your font?

Comment: SecureCRT, Consolas. Just `eshell -> make` will trigger this problem, the same in ubuntu terminal.